# how to format a string in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

im having problem with my string of time.. i wanted to format it so that it will display a more neat design.. can anyone help me with this one

here's my code:

```
 ViewBag.startTime = 
 (from a in test
  where a.ID == clientCustomerPositionShiftnfo.ID
  select new{ a.StartTime})
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select(a => a.StartTime != "Anytime"
  ? Convert.ToDateTime(a.StartTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
  : a.StartTime.Trim());
```

In my view:

```
    <input type="text" id="txtStartTime" name="txtStartTime" class="inputLong"
value="@ViewBag.startTime" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: Why the 'select new', why not just select the property?

Comment: in my view it doesnt show the value of the time instead it shows something like this
"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousTypeb`1[System.String],System.String]"

Comment: @tuespetre when i select the property i get the value but i cant format it... i need a way to format the starttime..

Comment: A cleaner design would be if the view formats the date using JavaScript and the browser's or users local settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) after your query:

```
ViewBag.startTime = 
    (from a in test
     where a.ID == clientCustomerPositionShiftnfo.ID
     select a.StartTime)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(t => t != "Anytime" ? Convert.ToDateTime(t).ToString("HH:mm:ss") : t)
    .First(); // or FirstOrDefault if your query might not return any results
```

Or perhaps more cleanly:

```
var startTime = 
    (from a in test
     where a.ID == clientCustomerPositionShiftnfo.ID
     select a.StartTime)
    .First(); // or FirstOrDefault if your query might not return any results
ViewBag.startTime startTime != "Anytime" 
    ? Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss") 
    : startTime;
```